# .each loop incrementing the index

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a recursive function and incrementing the index of the loop so it will start reading the XML file from the latest index loop.
But for some reasons the loop always restart from the beginning of the XML file instead than starting from the given index, passed here: `processXML(indexValue + 1);`
How may I solve this issue?
How do I tell to jQuery to restart the function but looping from the last given index and not from the start?

Please help me, this is driving me crazy. Who gives me the right answer I'll for sure accept it.
Thanks for any help!

```
function processXML(indexValue) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../broadcasted.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function(d) {
            var length = $(d).find('tweet').length;
            $(d).find('tweet').each(function(indexValue) {

                var cvdIndexId = $(this).find("index");
                var cvdTweetAuthor = $(this).find("author").text();
                var cvdTweetDescription = $(this).find("description").text();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (indexValue == (length - 1)) {
                        processXML(indexValue + 1);
                        //return false;
                        //count = index + 1;
                        //alert(index+1);
                    } else if (cvdTweetAuthor === "Animator") {
                        $('#cvd_bubble_left').html('');
                        obj = $('#cvd_bubble_left').append(makeCvdBubbleAnimator(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
                        obj.fitText(7.4);
                        $('#cvd_bubble_right').html('');
                    } else {
                        $('#cvd_bubble_right').html('');
                        obj = $('#cvd_bubble_right').append(makeCvdBubble(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
                        obj.fitText(7.4);
                        $('#cvd_bubble_left').html('');
                    }
                }, indexValue * 1000);
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have your ajax request inside the recursive function, that is probably slowing your page down majorly.

Comment: ok but it does not answer my question ... :( can you help? :D

Comment: Are you trying to search the xml you are getting back from the ajax? Just use .find() and then an each() loop maybe to test everything you found.

Comment: What is your goal? And what are you getting back from the ajax?

Comment: I need to read an XML file and its data. The problem is that the XML is written every time by a server script. So if the jQuery does not find any result will keep loading until new data is found. When new data is there it should start from the last data and not again from the top of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.  Call broadcastedXMLProcessStart() to kick it off.

```
var broadcastedXML;
var broadcastedXMLIndex=0;

function broadcastedXMLProcessStart() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../broadcasted.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function(d) {
          broadcastedXML = d;
          // set broacastedXMLIndex=0 here to start from beginning
          broadcastedXMLProcessTick();
        }
    });
}

function broadcastedXMLProcessTick() {
    var d = broadcastedXML;
    var nextIndex = broadcastedXMLIndex;

    var length = $(d).find('tweet').length;
    $(d).find('tweet').eq(nextIndex).each(function(idx) {    
        var cvdIndexId = $(this).find("index");
        var cvdTweetAuthor = $(this).find("author").text();
        var cvdTweetDescription = $(this).find("description").text();

        if (cvdTweetAuthor === "Animator") {
            $('#cvd_bubble_left').html('');
            obj = $('#cvd_bubble_left').append(makeCvdBubbleAnimator(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
            obj.fitText(7.4);
            $('#cvd_bubble_right').html('');
        } else {
            $('#cvd_bubble_right').html('');
            obj = $('#cvd_bubble_right').append(makeCvdBubble(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
            obj.fitText(7.4);
            $('#cvd_bubble_left').html('');
        }

    });
    if(nextIndex+1 > length) {
      setTimeout('broadcastedXMLProcessStart()', 1000);
    } else {
      broadcastedXMLIndex++;
      setTimeout('broadcastedXMLProcessTick()', 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm...the page started to do strange things. The DIVs that these function should create are created very fast and one onto another.

Comment: Just fixed some typos.  Try the last revision?  Link to the page?

Comment: ok works better now. But it starts anyway from the beginning of the file, instead than looping until new data is found and restart from the last looped data

Comment: Open up your developer/javascript console (if in Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+J).  Use console.log('foo') to log debug info there instead of the alert()s you were using earlier.  Make sure the nextIndex and length is what you're expecting. If so, it could be another issue. It's difficult for me to debug without access to the page.

Comment: The problem is here: if(nextIndex > length) nextIndex = 0; When it finds that there is no more data, instead of waiting for the next data to come it reloop from 0. How do I make it to wait that other data comes before continuing with the loop?

Comment: Oh, so you want to go fetch the latest xml file at that point?  Fixed.

Comment: Do you want it to fetch the latest XML file and start from the beginning, or start from the index in the XML where it left off?

Comment: You may want to increase the timer to re-pull the XML from 1000 to 5000 or more!